# Cannot save textbox was bound. ฺBut it can save if use the same binding with datagrdivew

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, textbox, bindingsource

I need to showing information like list and detail.
So I create a bindingSource use for Datagridview(list) and textbox(detail).

Binding seems successful. if I change selected row at datagridview , a textbox will change following a row.And I try to edit value in datagridview then save it. It can save.
But If try to change a value via textbox. A value don't have anything change.

```
Private ds As DatasetHTN
Private bs As BindingSource
Private ta As HTN_TEMP_ORDER_FILETableAdapter

ds = New DatasetHTN()
Me.bs = New BindingSource(Me.ds, Me.ds.HTN_TEMP_ORDER_FILE.TableName)
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bs
Me.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.bs, "REVISION_NO", True)

Me.ta.Fill(Me.ds.HTN_TEMP_ORDER_FILE)
```

I try to save by using these code

```
Me.ta.Update(Me.ds.HTN_TEMP_ORDER_FILE)
```

It can save if I edit vie some row of the datagridview. But it cannot save if I edit via textbox.
I need to know a datarow has some change or not? So I call this code for check change after I edit a value in textbox.

```
    Me.ds.AcceptChanges()
    Dim dsChange As DataSet = Me.ds.GetChanges()
    Dim dtChanged As DataTable = dsChange.Tables(0)
    If dtChanged IsNot Nothing AndAlso dtChanged.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim dr As DataRow = dtChanged.Rows(0)
        For Each dc As DataColumn In dtChanged.Columns
            Dim strOrg As String = String.Empty
            Dim strNew As String = String.Empty
            If Not IsDBNull(dr(dc.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Original)) Then
                strOrg = dr(dc.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Original)
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(dr(dc.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Current)) Then
                strNew = dr(dc.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Current)
            End If
            If strOrg <> strNew Then
                ShowMessage(strNew)
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

But I found GetChanges() return 'nothing'. It means textbox isn't change. Why?

Comment: What is `Me.ds.AcceptChanges()` doing, in your view? Have you tried to remove it? If the TextBox is bound to the same data source, can't you see the value change in the DataGridView when the text is validated (the change is acknowledged)?

Comment: Note that this: `Me.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.bs, "REVISION_NO", True)` adds a Binding where `DataSourceUpdateMode = OnValidation`, not `OnPropertyChanged`.

Comment: I added  AccepChange() before I click save button. And change DataSourceUpdateMode  to 'OnValidation'. Datagridview changed to be new value but it still cannot save. But I see a new value will be saved successfully  if I change selected row only after textbox is edited value. This solution isn't the best way because it will be a problem if I have only one row.

Comment: I know you added `.AcceptChanges()`, the question is if you know what that does. Well, simply don't do it. Call `.AccepChange()` when you first fill your DataTable (or, using a DataAdapter, set `AcceptChangesDuringUpdate` and `AcceptChangesDuringFill` to `true` <- which is the default), so all Rows will have the `Unchanged` status. If you call `.AcceptChanges()` after you have changed something, then `.GetChanges()` will return a `null` DataTable. This can compromise the procedure that saves the data to your database (I assume you're using a DataAdapter).

Comment: Me.ds.GetChanges() after Me.ds.AcceptChanges() will always return nothing, so the rest of your code is never run. As @Jimi said, remove the call to AcceptChanges()

Comment: You should also call `Validate` on the form and `EndEdit` on the `BindingSource` before trying to save, in order to commit any pending edits to the `DataTable`.

Comment: Thanks. It's work . I removed AcceptChanges and added Me.bs.EndEdit before call Update().